# Make somebody laugh Vs crack somebody up

Tags: verbs, expressions

Suppose someone makes you laugh so much that your stomach starts to hurt. In this case do the following sentences mean the same if you want to tell that person about what he has done:

> - You **made me laugh** so much that my stomach hurts.
> - You **cracked me up** so much that my stomach hurts.

Answer (score 3):

When someone says something funny and you start laughing uncontrollably you say: ["You crack me up!](http://ru.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crack%20me%20up)". The idiom ["to crack someone up"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crack+up) means "to make someone laugh very hard; to make someone break out laughing" (also, see [here](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/crack-up)).

I'm not sure if adding "so much that my stomach hurts" is needed at all.

[Here's the link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-make-someone-laugh) to the expressions which are related or synonymous to "to make someone laugh".

Comment: (+1) Just a small note. "Cracking up" does not necessarily imply that one's stomach hurt. So, if the speaker's stomach did in fact hurt after laughing, then the speaker could indicate that by saying "... so much that my stomach hurt".

Comment: @Max - Thanks a lot for pointing out; it's been taken note of.